# Fixed button moving if i scroll

Tags: css, button, jsx, sticky

i've got a Whatsapp Link button on the bottom right corner of my page, and when i change pages it stays where it's supposed to, but if i scroll down and change page, it moves to the top of the page. I don't know why is that happening.

Here's my CSS code:

```
    .floating {
  position: fixed;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #25d366;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index: 100000;
  right: 15px;
}

.my-float {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.whatsapp-container {
  position: sticky;
 
}
```

And the jsx:

```
<div className="whatsapp-container">
  <a
    href=""
    className="link-simulator floating"
    target="_blank"
  >
    <i className="fab fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, there was nothing wrong with what i was doing, i just had another posed-element from react rendering first and didn't let this one render, so the positioning thing didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I can´t reproduce the issue from the code you posted, but it probably has to do with the position:sticky of the whatsapp-container, have you tried removing that?

Comment: Yes, actually i added that because i though it will fix the issue. The <a> stays on the bottom right corner but when i scroll and change pages, for a second it moves to the top of the page before going back to the bottom right corner position